# Can a Wifi Adaptor of type 802.11ac connect to a 2.4 GHz network?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11ac

Can a laptop computer (e.g. HP 14-ck2330ng) with a Wifi Adaptor of type "802.11ac (1x1)" connect to a 2.4 GHz WiFi network? Or only a 5 GHz network?

Comment: I haven't seen any adapter that supports only 5GHz but not 2.4GHz so far.

Comment: 802.11 ac only supports 5.0 GHz

Comment: @Ramhound while it's true that 802.11ac only supports 5 GHz, 802.11ac devices are *always* backwards compatible with 802.11n, so this laptop with 802.11ac will have no problem at all connecting to an older router that only has a 2.4 GHz radio. It will simply fall back to 802.11n and 2.4 GHz. https://superuser.com/questions/1003221/802-11ac-with-a-2-4ghz-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched for the model number and found [specs on HP website](https://support.hp.com/th-en/document/c06459387). The wireless adapter is listed as:

> Intel® 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) Wi-Fi® and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo

So it does support 2.4 GHz (for b/g/n).